# Can I use a text file's content to create a filtered list for ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I am attempting to make a CMD script that will

1. Create a text file that lists file names followed by video codec (using ffprobe)
2. Create a new text from the list so that any file with x265 codec is removed from the list (and formated as
   `file "*filepath*"`
3. Run ffmpeg on the edited list to transcode remaining files to x265.

I have a script that does #1

```
for /R %%f IN (*.mkv,*.avi,*.mp4,*.m2ts,*.mts,*.rm,*.m4v) do echo "%%f" >>Probe.txt & ffprobe -v error -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=0 -print_format flat  -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name "%%f" >>Probe.txt & echo.  >>Probe.txt
```

which outputs

> "*filepath*"
> streams.stream.0.codec_name="*codec*"
>
> "*filepath*"
> streams.stream.0.codec_name="*codec*"

and I have a script that will do #3

```
for /R %%f IN (*.mkv,*.avi,*.mp4,*.m2ts,*.mts,*.rm,*.m4v) do ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "%%f" -c:v libx265 -c:a ac3 -x265-params crf=25 "%%f.mkv"
```

I am not sure if #2 is even possible though.

End result of task 2 should be that in probe.txt, any line that has a
`streams.stream.0.codec_name` value of anything besides `hevc` will have the line immediately above it written to a new txt file with the word file in front.

final goal is getting all three tasks to run under one batch file (each task running sequentially)

Is there any help on what I am missing to be able to unify these and get #2 to happen

Comment: So for all readers who are not codec experts, which of `"msmpeg4v3"` and `"mpeg4"` tells us it was encoded using the `x265` codec? Your programming question should be written with a Windows/batch-file audience as the main target, not a ffmpeg/codec audience.

Comment: @Compo that is merely an example of the output from a couple of files I used. The question is aimed at ffmpeg audience first, because it SPECIFICALLY deals with ffmpeg. the question IS posted with a windows and batch file flag for the reasons you posted as well. my concern is not only figuring out the code for the batch file, but also making sure it is compatible with ffmpeg.

Comment: No, you wanted help with batch file code, to perform a task based upon specific output, that, in general, was targeted towards somebody familiar with ffprobe, not ffmpeg. This was clear when you posted output from that command and did not, in any way, provide the output from any file which used the codec you wanted the code to identify. What you posted was frankly not good enough, and despite the fact you've accepted an answer, is of little purpose to future readership as is. Please [Edit] your question to at least include the ffprobe output from files using that codec, to rectify things.

Comment: @Compo what I posted *IS* the output. the command will list ONLY the codec as streams.stream.0.codec_name="codec". ffprobe is a part of ffmpeg, and therefore it is still relevant. I don't know what other information needs to be posted as i DID post all the relevant information. rather than argue about a topic you arent familiar with, (and frankly not helping anybody) you could have focused on the question posed: **"Is there any help on what I am missing to be able to unify these and get #2 to happen?"**

Comment: ffprobe is a separate executable file, and whilst it may generally accompany ffmpeg, it is not part of it at all. Also if you read the answer you've accepted, it also tells you that your question was lacking and assumptions needed to be made. Also I did not say I wasn't familiar with either ffmpeg or ffprobe, (I am), my comments are for the betterment of this question for future readers. Just to be clear, I am not going to answer your sub-question(s), whilst your initial post is lacking in the manner I have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

for /R %%f IN (*.mkv,*.avi,*.mp4,*.m2ts,*.mts,*.rm,*.m4v) do (
 ffprobe -v error -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=0 -print_format flat  -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name "%%f"|FIND "streams.stream.0.codec_name"|FIND "x265">NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "%%f" -c:v libx265 -c:a ac3 -x265-params crf=25 "%%f.mkv"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Totally untested**

I'm assuming that your commands are correct. With no information in the post about how to detect the target files, responders unfamiliar with the details of `ffmpeg` are forced to make assumptions.

So - assuming that the `ffprobe` output contains the strings `streams.stream.0.codec_name` and `x265` on the same line, then the result of the cascaded-finds will be that `errorlevel` will be set to `0` if both are found and non-`0` otherwise.

So - only run the `ffmpeg` line if the codec detected is not `x265`.

Note that a file `somename.mpg` would (theoretically) generate `somename.mpg.mkv` so if it is desired that the double-barrelled extension is avoided, you would need to make some minor modifications

```
 if errorlevel 1 if /i "%%~xf"==".mkv" (ffmpgcommand1
  ) else ffmpgcommand2
```

where the location and presence of the parentheses with respect to the keywords `if` and `else` are critical; `ffmpgcommand1` is the `ffmpeg` command with the destination filename being `"%%~dpnf.converted.mkv"` and `ffmpgcommand2` is the `ffmpeg` command with the destination filename being `"%%~dpnf.mkv"`

I've no idea what `ffmpeg` does should the destination filename already exist.

I'll repeat

**Theoretical only - totally untested**

Comment: just tested and works exactly as you described. it does just skip any file that already exists that ISNT the correct codec. I still have a couple of things to fix for MY needs, but this completely resolves need #2 (which I would still want to know if there's any possibility of that happening.) The naming isn't a big deal, as final step after all of this is they files get renamed, so I'm not concerned with that.

Comment: Well, #2 is possible. Do you really need the files? Would you prefer your files to list the results (x256 and not) or do you simply want to be able to process a file of the format you've shown for #1 as described?

Comment: Simply processing it is fine. the whole number 2 thing is more for education at this point (since your code completely bypasses its need)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (filename) do echo %%b|FIND "streams.stream.0.codec_name"|FIND "x265">NUL&if errorlevel 1 (set "prevline=%%~b") else (call echo %%prevline%%&set "prevline=%%~b")` should output that list